# Can anyone see where I am going wrong with my table creation/input

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When I try to insert data to my database I get the following error:

```
E/DATABASE OPERATION﹕ Database created/opened...
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table fixture_info has no column named match_opponent
E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting match_opponent=you match_venue=here match_time=16:00 match_date=27/12/2015
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table fixture_info has no column named match_opponent (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO fixture_info(match_opponent,match_venue,match_time,match_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Fixture {

    public static abstract class NewFixture {
        public static final String MATCH_DATE = "match_date";
        public static final String MATCH_TIME = "match_time";
        public static final String MATCH_OPPONENT = "match_opponent";
        public static final String MATCH_VENUE = "match_venue";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "fixture_info";
   }
}


public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CLUBHUB.DB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " +   Fixture.NewFixture.TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER, " +Fixture.NewFixture.MATCH_DATE + " TEXT, " + Fixture.NewFixture.MATCH_TIME + "TEXT, " + Fixture.NewFixture.MATCH_OPPONENT + " TEXT, "
        + Fixture.NewFixture.MATCH_VENUE + " TEXT );";

    public DBHelper(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION", "Database created/opened...");
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION", "Table create..." + CREATE_QUERY);
    }

    public static void addMatch(String date, String time, String opponent, String venue, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues cV = new ContentValues();

        cV.put(Fixture.NewFixture.MATCH_DATE, date);
        cV.put(Fixture.NewFixture.MATCH_TIME, time);
        cV.put(Fixture.NewFixture.MATCH_OPPONENT, opponent);
        cV.put(Fixture.NewFixture.MATCH_VENUE, venue);
        db.insert(Fixture.NewFixture.TABLE_NAME, null, cV);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION", "one row inserted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public Cursor getInfo(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        Cursor cursor;
        String[] projections = {Fixture.NewFixture.MATCH_DATE, Fixture.NewFixture.MATCH_TIME, Fixture.NewFixture.MATCH_OPPONENT, Fixture.NewFixture.MATCH_VENUE};

        cursor = db.query(Fixture.NewFixture.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null);

        return cursor;
    }

}
```

public class UpdateSchedule extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText addDate;
EditText addTime;
EditText addOpponent;
EditText addVenue;
Button addFixture;
Context context = this;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_updateschedule);

    addDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fixtureDateEdit);
    addTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fixtureTimeEdit);
    addOpponent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fixtureOpponentEdit);
    addVenue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fixtureVenueEdit);
    addFixture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addFixtureButton);
}

public void addFixture(View view) {
    String matchDate = addDate.getText().toString();
    String matchTime = addTime.getText().toString();
    String matchOpponent = addOpponent.getText().toString();
    String matchVenue = addVenue.getText().toString();

    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    DBHelper.addMatch(matchDate, matchTime, matchOpponent, matchVenue, sqLiteDatabase);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    dbHelper.close();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: your query to create table is wrong

Comment: If you added new columns to the schema, uninstall your app to get rid of the old database file and recreate it on next run.